# How do i print text into a unity program

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am relatively new to coding itself I am just confused on how to get text to print into my game that I type and get a text to update every second this is what I have so far

What i currently have written

[image]

Im using Unity 5.6.6f2

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What about using a newer up-to-date version of Unity? It is the year 2021 and currently the 2020.3 LTS should be your choice

Comment: I'm using this version for a class I'm taking in college thats what version there running on so I gotta use the same one for now so that I can turn in assignments

Comment: Very sorry about using a image very new to the site and the whole coding business lol

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a TextMesh component to the same object that your script is attached to. Then, from within your script you can use the GetComponent method and modify the text property on the TextMesh component. Try using this in your update method:

```
var textMesh = GetComponent<TextMesh>();
textMesh.text = "updated text";
```